# Potential jpg exploit in chinese gopro knock-off

Tags: camera, action, jpeg, exploit, digital

[Does this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJchh.png) look like potential jpg exploit attemp to you?

I picked up one of these GoPro knock-off action cameras. I tried recording some videos which seemed to work fine. I later went out with a buddy to shoot some pool and thought I wanted a cool timelapse of it.

Coming home I had hundreds of pictures, all of which seemed corrupt and couldn't be opened. I tried to peek with a hex editor why it might be and stumbled upon this stuff at the top of the file.

Does my camera try to hack me?

[Sample File](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjCliwlclKkXlCCFh4mlBihUqpFb)

(mandatory warning, open at own risk of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file doesn't contain the correct codes to make it recognizable as a JPEG image. It does contain all the correct information, but there are two bytes which are incorrect at the beginning. [The file should start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) with "FF D8 FF E1...". If you edit those two first bytes (they're 00 00 in your example), the resulting image is:

[image]

(I had to scale the image to get it to upload - it's 4 times larger on each side. The quality is quite nice)

Why this happens is a mystery to me, but very probably there's a bug in the recording software. It shouldn't be difficult to make a small program which reinstates the first two bytes. I suspect that the supplied software would concatenate the separate jpegs into a movie.

So no, your jpegs are not invading your computer.

This is Friistyler's script to correct the files (from the comment below):

```
for file in os.listdir("<dir>"):
    if os.path.isfile("<dir>%s" % file):
        with open("<dir>%s" % file, 'r+b') as f:
            f.seek(0)
            f.write('\xff\xd8')
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for that, i'll make a quick program to do this for every frame.

Comment: It worked like a charm... thank you for helping sorting this out.

For the people interested i simply ran this small python script:
`In [52]: for file in os.listdir("<dir>"):
   ....:     if os.path.isfile("<dir>%s" % file):
   ....:         with open("<dir>%s" % file, 'r+b') as f:
   ....:             f.seek(0)
   ....:             f.write('\xff\xd8')`

Comment: I've reproduced your script in my answer, just to make it more readable. Glade it worked ;-) I've had my share of problematic images.